# How to keep current tab active after page refresh jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two questions for my code.

First:
I want to keep last selected tab active after page refresh. Issue is when page refreshs the first tab is always active.

Second:
When a user comes at this page by the link change password. At this time I want to make second(change password) tab active.

Here my code:

```
<ul class="tab">
    <li class="current" data-tab="tab1">Account information</li>
    <li data-tab="tab2">Change Password</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content current" id="tab1">
    Tab1 Content comes Here!
</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="tab2">
    Tab1 Content comes Here!
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('ul.tab li').click(function(){
            var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
            $('ul.tab li').removeClass('current');
            $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

            $(this).addClass('current');
            $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Its obvious that when page loads, first tab will get the focus because of `current` class.

Comment: You have to save data somewhere when user clicked change password. Based on that data, you can dynamically insert `current` class to second tab

Comment: i am asking for the answer how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can save it to localStorage:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var last_id = localStorage.getItem('tab_id');
  if (last_id) {
    $('ul.tab li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
    $(".tab li").eq(last_id.match(/\d+/)[0]-1).addClass('current');
    $("#" + last_id).addClass('current');
  }
  $('ul.tab li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $('ul.tab li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
    localStorage.setItem('tab_id', tab_id);
  });
});
```

Here is the working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/k5j9qv4k/2/

As for second question, I am assuming you are not in this page which has tabs. Then you can save `tab_id='tab2'` to localStorage:

```
<a href="pageurl" onclick="localStorage.setItem('tab_id', 'tab2');">change password</a>
```

Comment: in my first question if user click any other tab like second tab and refresh the page after that i want second tab activated

Comment: When you click the `li`, you can save your tab_id to localStorage and when u reload it, you can get that id back on document ready

Comment: currently it is working correctly. thanks for it and help me for second question

Comment: when you click change password, that tab becomes active.

Comment: according to the second question change password is not the part of tab content. it is other at other location like  <a href="pageurl">change password</a>

Comment: When you click `pageurl` link, u can change `tap_id` in localStorage

Comment: this answer should be accepted, I put an effort and it satisfies both questions

Answer (score 0):

Use sessionStorage to store which tab is active and apply current class to active tab. Session storage variable still persists after page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(localStorage.getItem("CURRENT_TAB")=="tab2"){
     var x=$("li.tab2");
     $("li").not(x).removeClass("current");
     x.addClass("current");
  }
  $(".tab li").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("tab2")){
      localStorage.setItem("CURRENT_TAB","tab2");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab">
<li class="current tab1">TAB 1</li>
<li class="tab2">TAB 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: according to the second question change password is other link it is not the part of tab it like

<a href="pageurl">change password</a>

Answer (score 0):

You can do using local storage.
Write below code in your tab page.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('currentActiveTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
});
var currentActiveTab = localStorage.getItem('currentActiveTab');
if(currentActiveTab){
    $('#TABID a[href="' + currentActiveTab+ '"]').tab('show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, copied from [enter link description here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-keep-the-current-tab-active-on-page-reload-in-bootstrap.php)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if(activeTab){
        $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```

for those using bootstrap 5 change this ('a[data-toggle="tab"]') to `('a[data-bs-toggle="tab"]')`